# Is it possible to add a custom transition to a UIImagePicker custom overlay when switching capture modes?

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, ios8, uiimagepickercontroller

I added a custom overlay to a `UIImagePickerController` in my iOS 8 application.  However, when I switch capture modes (when I hit the corresponding `UIButton` to switch from photo to video and vice versa) there is a bit of "jerky pause".

In the standard `UIImagePickerController` there is a blur transition when switching capture modes **and I would like to implement something similar**.  I am somewhat familiar with custom transitions and segues in iOS 8, however in this case I'm not even sure where to start.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try the method: 
UIView.transitionFromView(<#fromView: UIView#>, toView: <#UIView#>, duration: <#NSTimeInterval#>, options: <#UIViewAnimationOptions#>, completion: <#((Bool) -> Void)?##(Bool) -> Void#>)

from view: self.view to your uiimagepickercontroller view

I hope it will be helpfull..

Comment: I'm going to try this as soon as I'm back in front of the computer, but isn't it already on the uiimagepickercontroller view when I switch capture modes?